# FlutterSecureStorage issue when getting value

Tags: flutter, async-await, future

I am simply saving the string value in FlutterSecureStorage and getting it on other page issue is its printing the value on other page but showing error

First page where I save the string

```
  if(data['access_token'].length > 2) {
    final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();
    await storage.write(key: 'token', value: data['access_token']);

    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyStatefulWidget()),
    );
  }
```

Second page where I am getting it

```
class _EventsState extends State<Events> {

  @override
  initState() async {
    // TODO: implement initState
    final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();
    String value = await storage.read(key: 'token');
    print(value);

    super.initState();
  }
}
```

Error is

```
_EventsState.initState() returned a Future.
```

Also attaching whole error

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> state.initState() must be a void method without an `async` keyword

That is literally what the error message says and it is correct.

You cannot do what you do right now in your `initState` method. You will need to find a way to save the Future you get from `storage.read` and wait for it's completion somewhere else.

Most likely using a `FutureBuilder` is your best option.

See [What is a Future and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/what-is-a-future-and-how-do-i-use-it).